# Extract ZIP's contents on screen but avoid extra information except of the file names

Tags: php, linux, command-line, zip

I am looking for a command that will print all the contents of an archive (including sub-folders and it's files) without extracting the actual archive on the disk, but only on screen.

I achieve something using some other questions and answers from this site, and here is my command:

```
unzip -l test.zip | awk '/-----/ {p = ++p % 2; next} p {print $NF}'
```

The output:

```
0 04-11-2009 13:43 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/ 1815 04-11-2009 13:43 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/README.txt 0 04-11-2009 13:43 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/src/ 5349 04-11-2009 13:42 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/src/jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2-sources.jar 26436 04-11-2009 13:43 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/LICENSE.txt 3819 04-11-2009 13:43 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/ChangeLog.txt 3314202 04-11-2009 13:42 jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2.war
```

As you can see the output is one line, and includes some extra information that I don't really need.

I want an output of this kind:

```
jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/
jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/README.txt
jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/src/
jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2/src/jodconverter-webapp-2.2.2-sources.jar
.
.
.
```

So not only I want to output the file names only (and their full path) and avoid any extra other information like `time` `permissions` and so on, but also I want to use something like `break-line` to distinguish different files.

Keep in mind that this command will run on a PHP file to get the contents of the file, so I don't know if this can help us to use the `<br>` to do the break lines.

Is that possible with a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't think a command that will return you back the output you need, but may someone else can know something more.

What I would do in your case is to split the line into array and play with it until you get what you want.

You actually have to find a pattern that will work for all cases.
With a brief look on the command's output I came with the following decisions:

1. You splitting the line using as separator the space (i.e explode() )
2. The pattern I can see is that there exist a time of the form `xx:xx` exactly before the actual file/directory ! So you can check if the current line is a valid 24-based time using a regular expression then that means if that is the case and you are in the `$i` position of the array the `$i+1` is what you are looking for, and therefore you can copy that to a new array.
3. Repeat

I think that is a bit pain, but at least is a solution.